# Tortoise and Hare, Method Not Drawing

Tags: java, for-loop, graphics, arraylist, draw

Working on a tortoise and hare project. This method should draw the the tortoises and hares but I'm getting an error message.

```
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
  super.paintComponent( g );

  // draw the finish line
  finishX = getWidth( ) - 20;
  g.setColor( Color.blue );
  g.drawLine( finishX, 0, finishX, getHeight( ) );

  if ( raceIsOn )
  {
      /*  loop through instance variable ArrayList racerList,
       *    which contains Racer object references,
       *    calling draw and move for each element. 
     */
      for (int i = 0; i < racerList.size(); i++)
    {
        move();
        draw (Graphics g);
    }

   }
   else // display racers before race begins
   {

    /*  loop through instance variable ArrayList racerList,
     *    which contains Racer object references,
     *    calling draw for each element. 
   */
       for (int i = 0; i < racerList.size(); i++)
        {
        draw();
        }

   }
 }
```

Here is part of the class i am trying to call

```
   /** abstract method for Racer's move
   */
   public abstract void move( );
   /** abstract method for drawing Racer
   *   @param   g    Graphics context
   */
   public abstract void draw( Graphics g );
```

Here is the entire class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RacePoly extends JFrame
{
  private ArrayList<Racer> racerList; // racers stored in ArrayList
  private static RacePoly app;
  private final int FIRST_RACER = 50;
  private int finishX; // location of finish line, dependent on window width
  private boolean raceIsOn = false;
  private RacePanel racePanel;

  /** Constructor
  *  instantiates list to track racers
  *  sets up GUI components
  */
  public RacePoly( )
  {
    super( "The Tortoise & The Hare!" );
    Container c = getContentPane( );
    racePanel = new RacePanel( );
    c.add( racePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    racerList = new ArrayList<Racer>( );
    setSize( 400, 400 );
    setVisible( true );
  }

  /** prepareToRace method
  *   uses a dialog box to prompt user for racer types
  *     and to start the race
  *   racer types are 't' or 'T' for Tortoise,
  *                   'h' or 'H' for Hare
  *   's' or 'S' will start the race
  */
  private void prepareToRace( )
  {
     int yPos = FIRST_RACER;        // y position of first racer
     final int START_LINE = 40;     // x position of start of race
     final int RACER_SPACE = 50;    // spacing between racers
     char input;

     input = getRacer( ); // get input from user

     while ( input != 's' && input != 'S' )
     {
        switch (input)
        {
        case 'T':
        case 't':
            racerList.add(new Tortoise( "Tortoise", START_LINE, yPos )); 
            yPos+=RACER_SPACE;
        break;
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
            racerList.add(new Hare( "Hare", START_LINE, yPos )); 
            yPos+=RACER_SPACE;
        break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "That was not a T or H you bitch." );
        break;
        }

        *  If input is 'H' or 'h',
        *      add a Hare object to the ArrayList named racerList
        *  The API of the Hare constructor is:
        *          Hare( String ID, int startX, int startY )
        *      a sample call to the constructor is
        *          new Hare( "Hare", START_LINE, yPos )
        *          where START_LINE is a constant local variable
        *            representing the starting x position for the race
        *          and yPos is a local variable representing
        *             the next racer's y position
        *
        *  After adding a racer to the ArrayList racerList,
        *          increment yPos by the value of
        *          the constant local variable RACER_SPACE
        *
        *  if input is anything other than 'T', 't',
        *          'H' or 'h', pop up an error dialog box
        *          a sample method call for the output dialog box is:
        *            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Message" );
        */

       repaint( );
       input = getRacer( ); // get input from user

     } // end while
   }
   private class RacePanel extends JPanel
   {
    /** paint method
    *    @param g   Graphics context
    *    draws the finish line;
    *    moves and draws racers
    */
    protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
      super.paintComponent( g );

      // draw the finish line
      finishX = getWidth( ) - 20;
      g.setColor( Color.blue );
      g.drawLine( finishX, 0, finishX, getHeight( ) );

      if ( raceIsOn )
      {
          /*  loop through instance variable ArrayList racerList,
           *    which contains Racer object references,
           *    calling draw and move for each element. 
         */
          for (int i = 0; i < racerList.size(); i++)
        {
            move();
            draw (g);
        }

       }
       else // display racers before race begins
       {

        /*  loop through instance variable ArrayList racerList,
         *    which contains Racer object references,
         *    calling draw for each element. 
       */
           for (int i = 0; i < racerList.size(); i++)
            {
            draw();
            }

       }
     }
   }

   /** runRace method
   *  checks whether any racers have been added to racerList
   *  if no racers, exits with message
   *  otherwise, runs race, calls repaint to move & draw racers
   *  calls reportRaceResults to identify winners(s)
   *  calls reset to set up for next race
   */
   public void runRace( )
   {
       if ( racerList.size( ) == 0 )
       {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,
                  "The race has no racers. exiting",
                  "No Racers", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            System.exit( 0 );
       }
       raceIsOn = true;
       while ( ! findWinner( ) )
       {
           Pause.wait(.03);
           repaint( );
       } // end while

       reportRaceResults( );
       reset( );
   }

   /** gets racer selection from user
   *   @return  first character of user entry
   *            if user presses cancel, exits the program
   */
   private char getRacer( )
   {
      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( this, "Enter a racer:"
                                          + "\nt for Tortoise, h for hare,"
                                          + "\nor s to start the race" );
      if ( input == null )
      {
         System.out.println( "Exiting" );
         System.exit( 0 );
      }
      if ( input.length( ) == 0 )
         return 'n';
      else
         return input.charAt( 0 );
   }

   /** findWinners:
   *    checks for any racer whose x position is past the finish line
  *    @return  true if any racer's x position is past the finish line
   *             or false if no racer's x position is past the finish line
   */
   private boolean findWinner( )
   {
     for ( Racer r : racerList )
     {
       if ( r.getX( ) > finishX  )
        return true;
     }
     return false;
   }

   /** reportRaceResults : compiles winner names and prints message
   *   winners are all racers whose x position is past the finish line
   */
   private void reportRaceResults( )
   {
     raceIsOn = false;
     String results = "Racer ";
     for ( int i = 0; i < racerList.size( ); i ++ )
     {
      if ( racerList.get( i ).getX( ) > finishX  )
      {
         results += ( i + 1 )  + ", a " + racerList.get( i ).getID( ) + ", ";
      }
     }

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,  results + " win(s) the race " );

   }

   /** reset:  sets up for next race:
   *       sets raceIsOn flag to false
   *       clears the list of racers
   *       resets racer position to FIRST_RACER
   *       enables checkboxes and radio buttons
   */
   private void reset( )
   {
      char answer;
      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( this, "Another race? (y, n)" );
      if ( input == null || input.length( ) == 0 )
      {
          System.out.println( "Exiting" );
          System.exit( 0 );
      }

      answer = input.charAt( 0 );
      if ( answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y' )
      {
          raceIsOn = false;
          racerList.clear( );
          app.prepareToRace( );
          app.runRace( );
      }
      else
          System.exit( 0 );
   }

   /** main
   *   instantiates the RacePoly object app
   *   calls runRace method
   */
   public static void main( String [] args )
   {
     app = new RacePoly( );
     app.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     app.prepareToRace( );
     app.runRace( );
   }
    }
```

Racer class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Racer
{
  private String ID;  // racer ID
  private int x;      // x position
  private int y;      // y position

  /** default constructor
  *    Sets ID to blank
  */
  public Racer( )
  {
    ID = "";
  }

  /** Constructor
  *    @param rID   racer ID
  *    @param rX    x position
  *    @param rY    y position
  */
  public Racer( String rID, int rX, int rY )
  {
    ID = rID;
    x = rX;
    y = rY;
  }

  /** accessor for ID
  *   @return  ID
  */
  public String getID( )
  {
    return ID;
  }

  /** accessor for x
  *   @return  current x value
  */
  public int getX( )
  {
    return x;
  }

  /** accessor for y
  *   @return  current y value
  */
  public int getY( )
  {
    return y;
  }

  /** mutator for x
  *   @param  newX   new value for x
  */
  public void setX( int newX )
  {
    x = newX;
  }

  /** mutator for y
  *   @param  newY   new value for y
  */
  public void setY( int newY )
  {
    y = newY;
  }

  /** abstract method for Racer's move
  */
  public abstract void move( );

  /** abstract method for drawing Racer
  *   @param   g    Graphics context
  */
  public abstract void draw( Graphics g );
}
```

Tortoise Class

```
/**  Tortoise class
*    inherits from abstract Racer class
*/

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tortoise extends Racer
{
   private int speed;
    private Random rand;

   /** Default Constructor: calls Racer default constructor
   */
   public Tortoise( )
   {
     super( );

     // percentage of time (between 90 - 99%) that this tortoise moves each turn
      rand = new Random( );
     speed = rand.nextInt( 10 ) + 90;
   }

   /** Constructor
   *    @param rID  racer Id, passed to Racer constructor
   *    @param rX    x position, passed to Racer constructor
   *    @param rY    y position, passed to Racer constructor
   */
   public Tortoise( String rID, int rX, int rY )
   {
     super( rID, rX, rY );

     // percentage of time (between 90 - 99%) that this tortoise moves each turn
      rand = new Random( );
     speed = rand.nextInt( 10 ) + 90;
   }

   /** move:  calculates the new x position for the racer
   *   Tortoise move characteristics: "slow & steady wins the race"
   *      increment x by 1 most of the time
   */
   public void move( )
   {
     int move =  rand.nextInt( 100 )  + 1;
     if ( move < speed )
       setX( getX( ) + 1 );
   }

   /** draw: draws the Tortoise at current (x, y) coordinate
   *       @param g   Graphics context
   */
   public void draw( Graphics g )
   {
     int startX = getX( );
     int startY = getY( );

     g.setColor( new Color( 34, 139, 34 ) ); // dark green

     //body
     g.fillOval( startX - 30, startY, 25, 15 );

     //head
     g.fillOval( startX - 10, startY + 5,  15, 10 );

     //flatten bottom
      g.clearRect( startX - 30, startY + 11, 35, 4 );

     //feet
     g.setColor( new Color( 34, 139, 34 ) );  // brown
     g.fillOval( startX - 27, startY + 10,  5, 5 );
     g.fillOval( startX - 13, startY + 10, 5, 5 );
   }
}
```

Hare Class

```
/** Hare class
*   inherits from abstract Racer class
*/

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hare extends Racer
{
   /** Default Constructor: calls Racer default constructor
   */
   public Hare( )
   {
     super( );
   }

   /** Constructor
   *    @param rID   racer Id, passed to Racer constructor
   *    @param rX    x position, passed to Racer constructor
   *    @param rY    y position, passed to Racer constructor
   */
   public Hare( String rID, int rX, int rY )
   {
     super( rID, rX, rY );
   }

   /** move:  calculates the new x position for the racer
   *   Hare move characteristics:  30% of the time, Hare jumps 5 pixels
   *                               70% of the time, Hare sleeps (no move)
   *   generates random number between 1 & 10
   *          for 1 - 7,  no change to x position
   *          for 8 - 10, x position is incremented by 5
   */
   public void move( )
   {
      Random rand = new Random( );
     int move =  rand.nextInt( 10 ) + 1 ;

     if ( getX( ) < 100 )
     {
      if ( move > 6 )
       setX( getX( ) + 4 );
     }
     else
     {
      if ( move > 8 )
       setX( getX( ) + 4 );
     }
   }

   /** draw: draws the Hare at current (x, y) coordinate
   *   @param g   Graphics context
   */
   public void draw( Graphics g )
   {
     int startY = getY( );
     int startX = getX( );

     // tail
     g.setColor( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
     g.fillOval( startX - 37, startY + 8,  12, 12 ) ;

     //body
     g.setColor( Color.GRAY );
     g.fillOval( startX - 30, startY,  20,  20 );

     //head
     g.fillOval( startX - 13, startY + 2, 13, 8 );
     g.fillOval( startX - 13, startY - 8, 8, 28 );

     //flatten bottom
     g.clearRect( startX - 37, startY + 15, 32, 5 );
   }
}
```

Comment: Give then fact that you've not provided a runnable example at all, maybe you'd like to share the error message you're getting...

Comment: `draw (Graphics g);` looks wrong...shouldn't that be `draw (g);` and I'm not convinced by `draw();` but then again, I don't have any context to be able to draw a conclusion...

Comment: If those are abstract methods, they need some sort of implementation somewhere? And, as for what MadProgrammer said, in the first for loop, you shouldn't have Graphics in the method call, just g. So, `draw(g);`

Comment: @MadProgrammer there are the other classes

Comment: @Tristan There are the other classes

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Tristan "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method draw() is undefined for the type RacePoly.RacePanel" and then a whole long list of problems

Comment: Line 65 you are missing a / in front of your comment block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your original draw method, you need to actually call draw on something that extends your Racer object,

```
    /**
     * paint method
     * 
     * @param g
     *            Graphics context draws the finish line; moves and draws
     *            racers
     */
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // draw the finish line
        finishX = getWidth() - 20;
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(finishX, 0, finishX, getHeight());

        if (raceIsOn) {
            /*
             * loop through instance variable ArrayList racerList, which
             * contains Racer object references, calling draw and move for
             * each element.
             */
            for (int i = 0; i < racerList.size(); i++) {
                racerList.get(i).move();
                racerList.get(i).draw(g);
            }

        } else // display racers before race begins
        {

            /*
             * loop through instance variable ArrayList racerList, which
             * contains Racer object references, calling draw for each
             * element.
             */
            for (int i = 0; i < racerList.size(); i++) {
                racerList.get(i).draw(g);
            }

        }
    }
```

I also noticed you used something odd for Pause? Just use, `Thread.sleep(30);` instead. After making those changes I was able to run the program fine.

Comment: Dang, I thought I tried this earlier! I think my syntax was off though. Thanks so much!!!